# Importing common js file to vite

Tags: ecmascript-6, vite, commonjs

I'm trying to transition from Gulp to Vite. I have a navbar plugin using common js files. Using it in html in script tags is no problem. What i'm trying to do is to bundle the code with the rest.

So in my **main.js** file i do this:

```
...
import './js/navigation.js'
const navigation = new Navigation(document.getElementById("navigation"))
...
```

and this gives **'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'root[pluginName] = factory(pluginName)')**' error.

The error is coming from this part of the file:

```
; (function (root, factory) {
var pluginName = 'Navigation';

if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], factory(pluginName));
}
else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(pluginName);
}
else {
    root[pluginName] = factory(pluginName); //<-- This part gives the error
}
}(this, function (pluginName) {
...
```

I'm fairly new to this ES6 concept, and i can't figure it out what should i do to fix this.